# Is RRD Consolidation Deceiving Me?

Tags: rrdtool

The gap in this graph is when the reboot happened. The memory drop is before the reboot (There is 16 GB in the machine, and `free` confirms the drop -- so it isn't a graph issue).

Is the memory drop actually before the reboot, or is this just a trick due to RRD consolidation?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the drop indeed happened about a week before the reboot, as the consolidation phase is visible in form of the small step in the dropping graph, where averaging is taking place.